# Having an issue with the fopen() php function

Tags: php, file, fopen, mkdir

I have a `users` directory and a child directory for the login/register system.  I have a file, `testing.php`, to try to figure out how to create a directory in the `users` directory AND create a PHP file within that same directory.  Here's my code:

```
<?php

$directoryname = "SomeDirectory";
$directory = "../" . $directoryname;

mkdir($directory);

$file = "../" . "ActivationFile";

fopen("$file", "w");

?>
```

I'm able to get `mdkir($directory)` to work, but not the `fopen("$file", "w")`.

Comment: Have you tried `fopen($file, "w");`?

Comment: @rafaelcpalmeida That's in the code I posted above.  It didn't create the file.

Comment: does `fopen` return a handle at all?  I notice you have no file extension on the filename.

Comment: @DevDonkey Even if I did exclude the file extension, the file should've still been created.  In this case, if my file wasn't created (and it didn't), it should've returned `False`.

Comment: what is the error you get (if any). As others pointed out: you create a directory, but not a file, so the file won't exist. Also: use `fopen($file, "w");` instead of `fopen("$file", "w");`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and check permissions.

Comment: so... ^ what about that? any errors? folder can be written to? you have answers below, although I don't see how that would help any. ping me if you need me, I am moving on.

Comment: @Jordumus thanks for the quick tips.  I will use your comment an the answers below and hopefully I can solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [`touch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php) in order to create a file:

> If the file does not exist, it will be created.

You also forgot to re-use `$directory` when specifying the filepath, so the file was not created in the new directory.

As reported by [Fred -ii-](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1415724/fred-ii) in a comment, error reporting should also be enabled. Here is the code with these changes:

```
<?php

// Enable error output, source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php#85096
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$directoryname = "SomeDirectory";
$directory = "../" . $directoryname;

mkdir($directory);

$file = $directory . "/ActivationFile";

touch($file);
```

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly!  I finally understand how to do something like this, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this, this should normally solve your problem.
PHP delivers some functions to manipulate folder & path, it's recommended to use them.
For example to get the current parent folder, you can use [dirname function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php).

```
$directoryname  = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/SomeDirectory";

if (!is_dir($directoryname)) {
    mkdir($directoryname);
}

$file = "ActivationFile";
$handle = fopen($directoryname . '/' . $file, "w");
fputs($handle, 'Your data');
fclose($handle);
```

This line is equivalent to **"../SomeDirectory"**

```
dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/SomeDirectory";
```

So when you open the file, you open **"../SomeDirectory/ActivationFile"**

```
fopen($directoryname . '/' . $file, "w");
```

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
$dirname = $_POST["DirectoryName"];  

$filename = "/folder/{$dirname}/";  


if (file_exists($filename)) {  
    echo "The directory {$dirname} exists";  
} else {  
    mkdir("folder/{$dirname}", 0777);  
    echo "The directory {$dirname} was successfully created.";  
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.